# How to find files which includes specific file through cscope

Tags: linux, cscope

We can easily search all the files which include that specific file using cscope gui tool. Exact option to be used for this purpose is :

```
....
Find files #including this file:
```

When I use this gui tool to search, It gives me thousands of references and all of them would be shown as page by page.

Is there any way to write all such files which includes that specific file through cscope console?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915971/cscope-how-to-use-cscope-to-search-for-a-symbol-using-command-line) may help you.

Comment: @user6435535, No. It did not.